# How can I update an existing record to have a new auto_increment id in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table with primary key (its name is "id") defined as auto_increment. I use NULL in INSERT statements to "fill" the id value. It works, of course. However now I need to "move" an existing record to a new primary key value (the next available, the value is not so much important, but it must be a new one, and the last one if ordered by id). How can I do it in an "elegant" way? Since the "use NULL at INSERT" does not work too much with UPDATE:

```
update idtest set id=NULL where id=1;
```

This simply makes the id of the record zero. I would expect to do the same thing as with INSERT, but it seems my idea was incorrect.

Of course I can use "INSERT ... SELECT" statement, then a DELETE on the old one, or I can use something like MAX(id) + 1 to UPDATE the id of the old record in one step, etc, but I am curious if there is a finer solution.

Also, the MAX(id) solution doesn't seem to work either by the way:

```
mysql> update idtest set id=max(id)+1 where id=3;
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
mysql> update idtest set id=(select max(id)+1 from idtest) where id=3;
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'idtest' for update in FROM clause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are trying to update same table is wrong but you can use join on same table

```
update idtest t
join (select id +1 as id
    from idtest order by id desc 
    limit 1) t1
set t.id=t1.id
where t.id=3;
```

or

```
update idtest t
join (select max(id) +1 as id
    from idtest ) t1
set t.id=t1.id
where t.id=3;
```

Comment: Yes, that's my problem that I'm not so much familiar with joins somehow, I prefer subqueries more, at least it's more readable (for me!). Thanks!

Comment: ... but maybe I should use this version anyway, as the side effect of the auto_increment value discussed at the answer involving the information_schema. I guess I should learn more MySQL and SQL in general anyway.

Comment: Is there a way I can use this to update multiple rows (ex `where t.ID > 461 and t.ID < 519`) ?
The current code will try using the same ID for each update which will fail due to duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I believe:

```
UPDATE users SET id = (SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'users') WHERE id = 2;

select * from users;
```

I used by own tables substitute yours.

`test` is database name, `users` is table name and `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT` in my case.

**EDIT: My Query above works perfect but its side effects are somewhat 'dangerous', upon next insert as `AUTO_INCREMENT` value will collide with this recently updated record so just next single insert will fail. To avoid that case I've modified above query to a transaction:**

```
START transaction;

    UPDATE users SET id = (SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
        FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test'
        AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'users') WHERE id = 2;

    #renew auto increment to avoid duplicate warning on next insert
    INSERT IGNORE INTO users(username) values ('');

COMMIT
```

Hope this will help someone if not OP.

Comment: Hmm, not as short as I would have liked initially, but it seems to be OK, thanks.

Comment: hang on a sec, there is a serious problem with my answer let me update

Comment: I would've delete it, but hope someone will improve it thats why i am not going to delete it right now.

Comment: Oh, I thought auto_increment value in information_schema would be adjusted automatically by the mysql server, but it's not then ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`REPLACE INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) clause to do the trick.

From the manual:

*REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See Section 13.2.5, "INSERT Syntax".*

**EDIT**
My mistake (in the comments) that you have to have two unique constraint to achieve this:

When you use the auto_increment value to REPLACE the record, the record will be replaced with the give ID and will not change (however the AI value will increment).

You have to exclude the AI column from the query. You can do that if you have one more UQ constraint.

Check this SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a702e

The first query will replace all the records (but the id's value will not change).
The second one will replace it too, and the new AI value will be used. (Please note, that the second query does not contain the `id` column, and there is a UQ constraint on the `some` column).

You can notice, that the second query uses higher AI values than it is excepted: this is because the first replace incremented the AI value.

If you do not have two unique keys (one for the AI and one for another columns), the REPLACE statement will work as a normal INSERT statement!

(Ofcourse you can change one of the UNIQUE KEYs with a PRIMARY KEY)

Comment: replace into idtest select * from idtest where id=3;
I thought it will do the trick then, but sadly not. It's accepted, but the primary key (id) didn't change.

Comment: Does the `id` column in `idtest` is a `PRIMARY KEY` or is there a  `UNIQUE` constraint which uses that column?

Comment: create table idtest ( id bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, some varchar(255) not null );

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. It would be nice, however in the real situation I met the problem (of course my idtest table is really only a simplified test, not the production environment) does not allow too much to alter the schema. Otherwise the "replace into ... select" would be short, nice, etc, but I think I have to stay with the answer involving the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. According to my test it works, without adding another constraint or any other modification in the schema.

Comment: You are welcome! You should not accept this answer if it is not solve your problem :)